# Error while using DB lookup in Mule Datamapper

Tags: mule

[image]

In datamapper I am using DB lookup and connecting Mysql table to get two fields - account and name. While calling the lookup I am getting error saying "lookup is not defined"

```
output.userId = lookup(GetAccount).get([input.account_user_id]).name;
```

Getting error like,

```
output.userId = lookup(GetAccount).get([input.account_user_id]).account;" failed.
    at org.mule.el.mvel.DataMapperExpressionLanguage.evaluate(DataMapperExpressionLanguage.java:71)
    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform.transform(MelRecordTransform.java:53)
    at org.jetel.component.Reformat.execute(Reformat.java:271)
    ... 15 more
  Caused by: [Error: unresolvable property or identifier: GetAccount]
[Near : {... put.userId = lookup(GetAccount).get([input.accoun ....}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head it looks pretty much that you are missing quotes around GetAccount and therefor you are actually using it as a variable rather than as a string.

Comment: I think what I wrote above is mule standard. When I change to the way you said it thrown error - `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter must be either a String or a LookupTable.`. It will be default when you drag the LoopupTable to output files. I did not do anything manual.

Comment: Oh I see, I just tried to replicate your project and I get a slightly different syntax with some protection at the beginning. The only thing I can suggest is to upgrade to a newer version to test. And then at least you can share which version is affected and if applies, which one is not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After editing the mapping file (GRF file) it was solved. The issue was caused by renaming of the lookup table name. In the code of GRF file I have found that table name was not changed in all places. After replacing the old names with the new one, it was working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and Lenka's comment is correct.  Basically, if you change the lookup table name in Datamapper, Anypoint Studio only updates the name attribute and not the ID attribute in the LookupTable tag in the GRF file.  You have to manually update the ID attribute to match the Name attribute.  Example tag below.

```
<LookupTable flow-ref="lookupFlow" id="lookupTest" key="test" metadata="841fa76b-3d1e-4ba6-b7d7-97a879283764711f1cb" name="lookupTest" type="muleFlowLookup">
```